# Counting the instances of a motif for groups using awk

Tags: unix, awk

I have a file that is over 20gb (so tons and tons of lines.)  The lines look something like this:

```
group1 motifA
group1 motifD
group1 motifD
group1 motifRalph
group1 motifA
group2 motifDenzel
group2 motifRodger
group2 motifHector
group2 motifDenzel
group2 motifA
group2 motifXYZ
group2 motifA
group2 motifDenzel
group3 motifHector
group3 motifRalph
group4 motifA
...
group10389
```

I want to create a summary file that lists what motifs appear in each group and how many times. For example:

```
group1 motifA 2
group1 motifD 2
group1 motifRalph 1
group2 motifDenzel 3
group2 motifRodger 1
group2 motifHector 1
```

But I want this for all of the motifs.  I know that with awk you can use count such as:

```
awk '{count[$1]++} END
```

But how to do this for the counting of groups like I have described? Much appreciated!

Comment: By seeing your profile could see sometimes you don't select an answer as correct one, give it sometime when you have enough responses try to select anyone of them as correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention you have a 20GB file, with potentially a lot of different lines. In the worst case, each line is different. This implies you would need 20GB of memory if you want to do something like this.

```
awk '{a[$0]++}END{for (i in a) print i, a[i] }'
```

So this approach is not really helpful. From your input, it looks like your file is sorted by the first column. If this is the case, the following might help:

```
awk '($1 != key) { for(i in a) print i, a[i]; delete a }
     {a[$0]++; key = $1}
     END { for(i in a) print i, a[i] }' file
```

But again this might not work as expected as the file could contain only a single group and again you might need 20 GB of memory.

The best approach is to use `sort` and `uniq`. GNU sort is designed so it can easily handle files which are much bigger than the total amount of memory in your system. You might, however, need to add a couple of extra options:

> **`--temporary-directory=tempdir`:** Use directory `tempdir` to store temporary files, overriding the `TMPDIR` environment variable. If this option is given more than once, temporary files are stored in all the directories given. If you have a large sort or merge that is I/O-bound, you can often improve performance by using this option to specify directories on different disks and controllers.
>
> *This option might be needed as `/tmp` might not be able to hold enough disk space to do the sort of 20GB of data*
>
> **<sub>source: [GNU Coreutils Sort Invocation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html)</sub>**

```
sort --temporary-directory=/home/user/tempdir bigfile | uniq -c
```

To determine which approach you need to use, I would suggest to:

1. First count the total entries per group:

   ```
   $ cut -d " " -f1 file | uniq -c | sort -n | awk '(NR==1)END{print $0}'
   ```

   The above line will print the smallest and largest group (assuming your file is group sorted)
2. Get the maximum length of a line:

   ```
   $ awk { l=length($0); m=m<l?l:m } END {print m}' file
   ```
3. If `n_max` (largest group) times `l_max` (largest length) is of the order of your total memory, use the `sort` option
4. Otherwise, use the second option.
5. Never use the first option for large files.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following. Reading Input_file 2 times here.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$2]++;next} a[$1,$2]{print $0,a[$1,$2];delete a[$1,$2]}' Input_file Input_file
```

***2nd approach:*** By reading Input_file only 1 time(It could be time taking as per Tiw's comment in comment section since whole Input_file is being loaded to memory or so).

```
awk '!a[$1 FS $2]++{b[++count]=$1 OFS $2;} {c[$1 FS $2]++}  END{for(i=1;i<=count;i++){print b[i],c[b[i]]}}'  Input_file
```

Comment: `END` block to output all data is not a good idea for 20GB file imho.

Comment: @Tiw, yes true, I mentioned it as that is one of the approach to solve this, I leave this up to OP since we don't have that much big size file for tests.

Comment: Yeah, hard choice.

Comment: @Tiw, added fair warning in there now too, thanks for letting know.

Comment: This will fail if there are N GB of unique entries in the data and you do not have N GB of available memory.

Answer (score 2):

not tested with 20Gb file but usually you can do with:

```
sort inputfile |uniq -c

  2 group1 motifA
  2 group1 motifD
  1 group1 motifRalph
  2 group2 motifA
  3 group2 motifDenzel
  1 group2 motifHector
  1 group2 motifRodger
  1 group2 motifXYZ
  1 group3 motifHector
  1 group3 motifRalph
  1 group4 motifA
  ......
```

Comment: This will fail if `/tmp` or `TMPDIR` cannot hold 20GB of data

Answer (score 0):

if your groups are grouped, this approach should work the best.

```
$ awk 'function pr() {for(k in a) print p,k,a[k]} 
       p!=$1 {pr(); delete a; p=$1} 
             {a[$2]++} 
       END   {pr()}' file

group1 motifA 2
group1 motifD 2
group1 motifRalph 1
group2 motifA 2
group2 motifHector 1
group2 motifDenzel 3
group2 motifXYZ 1
group2 motifRodger 1
group3 motifHector 1
group3 motifRalph 1
group4 motifA 1
```

scans the file only once, doesn't need sorted input and only keeps one group block of unique fields in memory.

Comment: This will fail if the input file is 20Gb big with N Gb of unique data with N larger than total memory available on the system.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Perl also

```
$  perl -lane ' $kv{$_}++;END { foreach(keys %kv) { print "$_ $kv{$_}" } } ' steveman.txt
group3 motifHector 1
group2 motifXYZ 1
group2 motifDenzel 3
group1 motifD 2
group2 motifA 2
group1 motifRalph 1
group3 motifRalph 1
group1 motifA 2
group4 motifA 1
group2 motifRodger 1
group2 motifHector 1
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, using [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/):

```
 $ datamash -t ' ' groupby 1,2 count 2 < input.txt
group1 motifA 1
group1 motifD 2
group1 motifRalph 1
group1 motifA 1
group2 motifDenzel 1
group2 motifRodger 1
group2 motifHector 1
group2 motifDenzel 1
group2 motifA 1
group2 motifXYZ 1
group2 motifA 1
group2 motifDenzel 1
group3 motifHector 1
group3 motifRalph 1
group4 motifA 1
```

(This assumes your input file is already sorted based on the two fields; if not add -s; dunno how it'll work with a 20gig file though)